# infix to postfix conversion and evaluation

Tags: postfix-notation

I have a complex problem, I am getting formulas form the database and I need to evaluate them. I choose to convert them to post fix...and evaluate them the problem is that..
my formulas are like

```
roundoff(vd,2);
udV=lookup(uv*dse,erd);
ude=if(er>es)?sr:ss;
```

Can anyone find a solution for these type of conversions and evaluations...

Comment: What do they look like before conversion?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question, your are asking how to convert from infix to postfix, does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No, not without some more clarification from you.  Perhaps you could tell us what sort of technology you are using and what some, at least, of your functions mean.  As it stands I recommend that you use Mathematica because it's probably powerful enough to tackle this type of problem.  If you don't have access to Mathematica, perhaps you could hook in to Wolfram Alpha for evaluations.

Comment: I am using Xcode ...i am developing an iphone app which has to do some calculations from the formulas which it downloads from the server..i have no idea regarding the Mathematica..which u have mentioned